# How to calculate time taken by each thread in a request if suppose i have 500 threads

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I want to know the exact time taken by each request while performing load test in jmeter. Suppose, I am running load test for 100 users and have 10 requests. I want to know the time taken by each specific request in this process. Is there any way to know this. if so, please let me know

I have already used summary, aggregate, view result tree, error, assertion in my load test and they do not cover my need

I am expecting time taken by each request for each user but actually i am not able to get this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain using example what you expect that a listener can't do?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [View Results in Table](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table) listener.

> This visualizer creates a row for every sample result.
>
> By default, it only displays the main (parent) samples; it does not display the sub-samples (child samples). JMeter has a "Child Samples?" check-box. If this is selected, then the sub-samples are displayed instead of the main samples.

[image]